# Facebook Like Box plugin not working on iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, facebook

I have used the Facebook like box social plugin to add to a website www.themercantilehotel.com.au however it doesn't show up on the iphone/ipad, when it does work on all browsers.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your code, where you've added the plugin?

Comment: I second what jiffy said, what is the error and can we please see the code you have used so we can offer some help?

Comment: I tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
Then read somewhere iFrame might work, so have used that instead now:

Comment: Where I want plugin to be:

<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTheMercantileHotel&amp;width=305&amp;height=395&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=false&amp;appId=132622040153565" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 305px; height: 305px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have set your Facebook-page to some sort of restriction, age or location. If you try accessing your site while you are logged in on Facebook, in the same browser, you will be able to view your like box. The solution is to change the restriction of your Facebook page. Then logged out users will be able to view the like box as well.

Facebook can't control the age or location of offline users and decides not to show the box.